# Authenticate .NET application for administrative access to Active Directory domain using certificate

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I am writing a C# application that manages users, groups, permissions, etc. on an Active Directory domain. My application currently works only if run on a domain computer using a domain admin user account. I would like to make my application work on any computer using any user account, regardless of domain membership or permissions. I do not want to store an administrator password in my application. This seems like a job that could be handled by a certificate.

So, how can I authenticate my application on an AD domain using a certificate, in order to grant my application administrative privileges on the domain, regardless of the context (user, computer, etc.) in which my application is running?

My application uses System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry objects to manipulate the domain. I would like my existing code to remain as intact as possible, so a solution that works with this API is preferred. Additionally, I would like to avoid installing additional services (e.g. IIS) if possible.

The following code seems to do what I want, but it still requires my application to know the username and password of a domain admin account.

```
DirectoryEntry domain = Domain.GetDomain(new DirectoryContext(
    DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer,
    "domain controller ip", "admin username", "admin password"))
    .GetDirectoryEntry();
```

If I could do exactly like the code above, but with a certificate in place of the username and password, I'd have it.